# Mule - Dynamic Path - File component

Tags: file, path, mule, payload

I use a `file component` in my `mule flow` that add the `payload` in that file.
The mule flow is:

`HTTP Listener` => `Payload` => `File` => ...

The component in XML:

```
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="${test}" outputPattern="tested_#[function:datestamp:yyyyMMdd].log" connector-ref="File" responseTimeout="1000" doc:name="File"/>
```

When I generate the file, it create a folder called `test` in `mule-esb-directory\bin` but I want to create it in the project directory for example:
`mule-esb-directory\app\MyMuleProject`.

I use a `properties file` to set the path but it does not work.

**Now:** `mule-esb-directory\bin\test`

**I want:** `mule-esb-directory\app\MymuleProject`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
src/main/resources/
```

Or try with absolute path, like this

```
/opt/mule-esb-directory/app/MymuleProject
```

Comment: I tried that but it creates like this: `mule-esb-directory\bin\src\main\resources`

Comment: At runtime, the root folder is the same where the project is located (Assuming you have a single project).

In theory, you can try this

`<file:outbound-endpoint path="/" outputPattern="tested_#[function:datestamp:yyyyMMdd].log" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>`

But the file connector does not permit, then you can do this:

`<file:outbound-endpoint path="../#[app.name]" outputPattern="tested_#[function:datestamp:yyyyMMdd].log" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>`

I do not think it's the best practice, but it works.

Comment: Thanks ! I `use ../apps/#[app.name]/errors` and it works fine